# Cannot extract some numbers from strings

Tags: python

I want to extract numbers from a column in a dataframe but it returns to NaN. Take a sample dataframe as an example:

```
smb = pd.DataFrame(data = {'group': ['a','b','c'], 
                           'coeff' : ['0.10***', '0.02**', -0.03]})
```

when I try to create another columne by extracting numbers from the `coeff` column:

```
smb['coeff2'] = smb['coeff'].str.extract('(\d?.\d+)')
```

The `coeff2` columns are `0.10, 0.02, NaN`. I expect to return `0.10, 0.02,-0.03`. Not sure where I did incorrectly.

Comment: Did you mean `\d`? And what about the decimal point?

Comment: `smb['coeff'].str.extract('(\d+\.\d+)')` - you seem to have forgotten the decimal part and the slash needs to be a backslash.

Comment: `smb['coeff'].str.extract('(\d?.\d+)')` will work even if there is no decimal point. By the way that won't work with an actual number (0.03 in your dataset)

Comment: yes, if using (\d?.\d+), the 0.03 in the dataset is still NaN; I hope to make it return to 0.03 as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
import pandas as pd
smb = pd.DataFrame(data = {'group': ['a','b','c'], 
                           'coeff' : ['0.10***', '0.02**', 0.03]})
smb['coeff2'] = smb['coeff'].astype(str).str.extract(r'(\d?.\d+)')
```

Output:

```
    group   coeff   coeff2
0   a   0.10*** 0.10
1   b   0.02**  0.02
2   c   0.03    0.03
```

Comment: Thank you. How about 0.03? It still returns to NaN

Comment: You need to escape the dot. This will return `s10` for `'s10***'`

Comment: Even I escape the dot using (\d?.\d+), the last number, 0.03 is still NaN. This question has not been fully answered and not identical to other questions.. Please reopen it.

Comment: @Warrior Just do `smb['coeff2'] = smb['coeff'].astype(str).str.extract('((?:-?\d\.)?\d+)')`